# American English pronunciation: basically or "basicly"?

Tags: pronunciation, american-accent

Does the final "a" drop out in words like "basically", "logically", etc, or should I pronounce it?

Comment: The `a` is usually completely elided, though rarely,  some American speakers might use a schwa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've lived in the United States my entire life. In my experience, native speakers always pronounce these words as *basicly* and *logicly*. The pronunciation *basical-ly* sounds distinctly foreign; in fact, in my experience, I think that the pronunciation *basical-ly* is the *most common* pronunciation mistake that I ever hear.

In slow and careful speech, I *could* imagine someone saying *logical-ly*, but the pronunciation *logicly* seems more common even then.

The spellings of *-al*, *-ly*, and *-ally* are frustratingly inconsistent. In the following list, each word is presented as *adjective* - *standard spelling of adverb* - *phonetic spelling of adverb*:

- public - public**ly** - public**ly**
- basic - basic**ally** - basic**ly**
- logic**al** - logic**ally** - logic**ly**
- intern**al** - intern**ally** - intern**ally**

Comment: Many people, when speaking in formal or stressful situations, or when they feel the need to be especially clear (or forceful, or persuasive), may adopt pronunciation which errs on the side of sounding out all nominal syllables of a word, even if it's not the accepted pronunciation. I think you'd categorize this as a kind of hypercorrection. But of course, if it happens often enough, then it becomes an accepted pronunciation.

Answer (score 0):

They are all correct, but the pronunciations 'basicly' and 'logicly' are far more common.